# Trying to remove a left border style from an a-element

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar that is like so:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonial.html">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And it has css like so:

```
.nav_bar {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  height:40px;
} 
.nav_bar ul {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  width:940px;
}
.nav_bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display:inline;
}
.nav_bar li a {
  text-align:center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 20px;
  width:147px;
  background:#000000;
  color:#eee;
  float:left;
}
```

As you can imagine, this puts a white line to the left of the  elements, Which I want except for the first one. I tried adding:

```
<a href="index.html" style="border-left:1px solid color:#000000">Home</a>
```

to the first li but it doesn't do anything, and in developer tools, it is crossed out with a orange triangle next to it. So, how would I accomplish the task at hand?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a slight error in your `border-left` syntax, it should be:

```
<a href="index.html" style="border-left:1px solid #000000">Home</a>
```

See this [introduction to CSS shorthands](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-css-shorthand/) for more info on the sort of syntax you should use.

Comment: @Kevin: You're very welcome, if I had a penny for every time I've made a mistake like this...

Answer (score 0):

Why not do
`.nav_bar li a:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}`

Or if you don't want it at all
`.nav_bar li a:first-child { border:none; }`

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child:

> The :first-child pseudo-class matches an element that is the first child element of some other element.
>
> In the following example, the selector matches any P element that is the first child of a DIV element. The rule suppresses indentation for the first paragraph of a DIV:
>
> ```
> div > p:first-child { text-indent: 0 }
> ```
>
> This selector would match the P inside the DIV of the following fragment:
>
> ```
> <P> The last P before the note.
> <DIV class="note">
>  <P> The first P inside the note.
> </DIV>
> ```
>
> but would not match the second P in the following fragment:
>
> ```
> <P> The last P before the note.
> <DIV class="note">
>  <H2>Note</H2>
>  <P> The first P inside the note.
> </DIV>
> ```